# Kubuntu bad spacing in global menu

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, globalmenu

Hi I'm not sure if it was after an update or a new program installation but my global menu in kubuntu 18.10 is now messed up, is not well spaced out as it was initially.

**Screenshot of global menu**

[image: screenshot of global menu]

There's nothing in the widget options.

It is back to normal after updating plasma.